# How to connect Microsoft SQL to Firebase

Tags: node.js, sql-server, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have to add data from Microsoft SQL to Firebase realtime database because our system on Microsoft SQL and Mobile app with flutter but when we send notification to android app from ms sql it doesn't notify when app is closed so I tried it with node.js but it isn't working.

```
const sql = require('mssql');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');


const serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");
const firebaseConfig = {
    databaseURL: "****"
};

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: firebaseConfig.databaseURL
});


const sqlConfig = {
  user: '***',
  password: '***',
  server: '***',
  database: 'master',
  options: {
    encrypt: true,
    trustServerCertificate: true
  }
};


const sqlQuery = 'SELECT * FROM Persons';


const dbRef = admin.database().ref('/todos'); 


sql.connect(sqlConfig).then(pool => {
  return pool.request().query(sqlQuery);
}).then(result => {
  const rows = result.recordset;

  
  rows.forEach(row => {
   
    const data = {
      primary_key: row.primaryKey,
      value: row.value
    };

   
    dbRef.child(row.primaryKey).set(data);
  });

 
  sql.close();
}).catch(err => {
  console.error('Error:', err);
});
```